# Is it good practice extending database entity classes?

Tags: symfony, class, doctrine, entity

I have a User Entity class in my symfony project. User class contain basic information that is required for authentication - username, password, email etc. however I am planning to add additional data. Like weight, height, favorite food etc.

Is it a good practice to define all the user bio and data in the user class. Or should the user class be extended with another entity class like for example a Member and then the Member should implement Premium Member  or Administrator class ?

If that so, should the entity classes also contain methods with business logic ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're describing various types of [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)). If you plan to have multiple similar entities that share several properties then this is a very smart approach.

Separately, when using Doctrine (as is "standard" with Symfony applications) you definitely do not want to include any business logic in your entities unless absolutely no other solution exists (unlikely). This is by design using the DataMapper pattern with Doctrine in contrast to the ActiveRecord pattern with ORMs like Eloquent (Laravel), and Ruby on Rails.

This article is a good overview of the differences between ActiveRecord and DataMapper; particularly referencing Doctrine and Ruby on Rails as contrasting approaches: https://pressupinc.com/blog/2014/11/orm-patterns-active-record-data-mapper/